# How to pass is a list of keys to a Redis Lua script and then iterate through them

Tags: redis, lua

In my service, which is hosted separately from my Redis cache, I generate a gather a bunch of keys from my database that I want to send to my Redis cache to do something with. Currently I'm making a bunch of individual calls from my service to Redis, issuing a bunch of individual commands for each key, which takes a really long time.

Is it possible to instead gather up these keys and issue bulk operations (maybe using Lua)? A couple of my use cases are:

- Deleting a list of keys. Can I do something like `call('DEL', unpack(KEYS))`?
- Copying values between pairs of keys. Can I iterate through pairs of keys and do something like `call('HMSET', KEYS[i], unpack(call('HGETALL', KEYS[i+1])))` (and iterate two at-a-time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use Lua script to gather up a bunch of individual commands.

- Deleting a list of keys.

```lua
for _, key in ipairs(KEYS) do
  redis.call("DEL", key)
end
```

- Copying values between pairs of keys

```lua
for i = 1, #KEYS, 2 do
  redis.call("COPY", KEYS[i], KEYS[i+1])
end
```